# Sequence alignment of extended IUPAC sequences

Tags: sequence-alignment

I want to align a short sequence to a reference, and both are encoded in the [extended IUPAC notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_notation) (i.e. 16 letters).

What alignment software can I use for that?

For example, in [Bowtie](http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/bowtie2/news.shtml) *"all non-A/C/G/T characters in reads become Ns",* so it ignores which extended letters are matching.

Comment: Found a very similar question here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/tool-for-nucleotide-alignment-with-all-nucleotide-codes-e-g-r-y-w-s-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Biostrings, depends on how large is your reference, if it is small, you can just pairwiseAlignment with the nucleotideSubstitutionMatrix which supposedly :

```
library(Biostrings)
data(phiX174Phage)

x = DNAString("TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT")

lapply(phiX174Phage,function(y)pairwiseAlignment(x,y,
substitutionMatrix = nucleotideSubstitutionMatrix()))

$Genbank
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92 

$RF70s
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92 

$SS78
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92 

$Bull
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92 

$G97
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92 

$NEB03
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: -------------TCCAWRSCGCAGAAGT...----------------------------
subject: GAGTTTTATCGCTTCCATGACGCAGAAGT...TAAAAATGATTGGCGTATCCAACCTGCA
score: -21491.92
```

If it is much larger, you can convert the sequence of interest to a pwm and find it in the reference fasta, like shown in [this example](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2009/SeattleNov09/Biostrings/MatchAlign.pdf)